# Convert JSON response to an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm currently in the process of building my first iOS app. As a part of this app I need to fetch some data from a webserver. The function below is part of that:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);

    // convert to JSON
    NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

    // show all values
    for(id key in res) {

        id value = [res objectForKey:key];

        NSString *keyAsString = (NSString *)key;
        NSString *valueAsString = (NSString *)value;

        NSLog(@"key: %@", keyAsString);
        NSLog(@"value: %@", valueAsString);
    }

}
```

This goes through the JSON data, which it fetches (You can see an example of the data below). However, for me to be able to put it into a table view, I need to convert this into an `NSArray`. Like this:

```
self.array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    @"Always put your fears behind you and your dreams in front of you.",
    @"A relationship with no trust is like a cell phone with no service, all you can do is play games.",
    @"People should stop talking about their problem and start thinking about the solution.",
    @"Dear Chuck Norris, Screw you. I can grill burgers under water. Sincerely, Spongebob Squarepants.",
    @"My arms will always be open for you, they will never close, not unless you're in them.",
    nil];
```

And as promised, this is the data from the server - the JSON response:

```
{"data": "[

     {"TVShow1":"Dexter", "Episodes":"125"},
     {"TVShow2":"Boardwalk Empire", "Episodes":"54"},   
     {"TVShow3":"Fargo", "Episodes":"10"},   
     {"TVShow1":"The Sopranos", "Episodes":"11"}

]"}
```

How can I change that to an `NSArray`?

Comment: why do you **need** to convert it to an array? You most definitely **can** use an `NSDictionary` to populate a table view, can't you? Anyway, what's even the relation between the two snippets you posted? There doesn't seem to be any...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change anything.

Your json is an object that contains a array already, called `data` in your case.

```
NSArray *data = [res objectForKey:@"data"];//for sake of demo but should be a property
NSLog(@"",data);//that's your data source
```

Then in `cellAtIndexRow` delegate, read the values:

```
cell.textLabel.text = data[indexPath.row][@"Episodes"];//that will display episode
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSJSONSerialization` is going to convert it to an `NSDictionary` for you, as shown.  From there, just access the array using the `data` key:

```
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

NSArray *data = res[@"data"];
if (!data) {

    NSLog(@"Error: no data array was found.");

}

// do something with the data array
```